# Use the arguments object instead of parameters

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, arguments

I found this piece of code used in a dependency injection implementation in javascript:

```
resolve: function() {
  var func, deps, scope, args = [], self = this;
  func = arguments[0];
  deps = func.toString().match(/^function\s*[^\(]*\(\s*([^\)]*)\)/m)[1].replace(/ /g, '').split(',');
  scope = arguments[1] || {};
  return function() {
    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    for(var i=0; i<deps.length; i++) {
        var d = deps[i];
        args.push(self.dependencies[d] && d != '' ? self.dependencies[d] : a.shift());
    }
    func.apply(scope || {}, args);
  }        
}
```

And I was wondering myself why that ugly `func = arguments[0]` was there, because I'd write that with just: `function(func) { ... }`... is there any difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* a difference:

```
function a(arg) { return arg; };
function b() { return arguments[0]; };
console.log(a.length); // 1
console.log(b.length); // 0
```

But I think it more to be compatible with `arguments[1] || {}` which is necessary to use the default value.

Comment: *"which is necessary to use the default value"* - No it's not. Why would it be?

Comment: well you could re-assign but thats often considered as bad code style

Comment: I would say using arguments instead of naming arguments in the function declaration is (generally) worse code style...

Comment: Ok this difference is pretty much obvious. I was asking instead if there was some different actual beahvior in the execution of the function... and there isn't, so thank you.